# Using PHPMailer when popen is disabled

Tags: phpmailer, popen

Is it possible to use PHPMailer to send an email from a php script on shared hosting where popen() is disabled? I am trying to send an email using the code below but get the error message "popen has been disabled for security reasons". On checking with my host provider it has indeed been disabled and cannot be enabled on shared hosting. Does this make PHPMailer unusable for me?

```
        $mail = new PHPMailer();
        $mail->SetFrom('info@byetunes.com', 'Byetunes');
        $mail->AddReplyTo($param['sender_email'], $param['sender_name']);
        $mail->AddAddress($receiverEmails[0]);

        $mail->isHTML(true);
        $mail->isSendmail(true);
        $mail->Subject  = $param['subject'];
        $mail->Body     = $message_body;

        $sendingStatus = $mail->send();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You only need `popen` because you're using `isSendmail` - why are you doing that?

If you use `isMail` (the default, most likely to work on shared hosting) or `isSMTP`, you don't need `popen`.

Comment: Thanks, that did the trick. I was using Sendmail because I thought it would be more reliable. I was originally having problems getting the emails to send successfully.